# When i release a new version of my database application, will the database be the new one?

Tags: android, database, assets

I am building a new application which uses a database that is pre-created from me.
I put the database in the assets folder so when a user first-time downloads the application the database will be copied from assets folder internal in the application.

**Now the question is what will happen when i release a new version of my application with a new updated (pre-created) database (same database schema with just with more records)**.

I think there will be a problem because the data **(database) is kept during an upgrade** (??). 
So when the user **first runs the new version** of my application the programm will NOT copy the new database fromm assets folder because there will be already a database with the same file name.

(every time the programm runs it checks if there is already a database, if not -first time- it copies the database internaly)

I want to know the answer to the above question before i publish my application so i will be prepared..

Thank you advance.

Comment: the answer is simple `yes` it will be the problem. You need to give versions to your `DB` and update it if new version is available.

Comment: you could change the database version of the database on a new release, this will trigger the update method of the database and you could delete the database and copy the new one from assets

Comment: And how can i solve that problem ? (programmatically i mean). Should i store the old database version and then delete the old database so that the new could be copied again from assets folder?